# Trouble with input using scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C so I'm having a bit of trouble with scanf().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int height;
int weight;

printf("Enter height in inches:\n");
scanf("%d", &height);

printf("Enter weight in pounds:\n");
scanf("%d", &weight);

printf("You are %d inches tall and weigh %d pounds.", height, weight);

return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the correct syntax but when I run it, it shows an empty screen and after I input 2 numbers it shows:

64

120

Enter height in inches:

Enter weight in pounds:

You are 64 inches tall and weigh 120 pounds.

According to some tutorials, it's supposed to display "Enter height in inches:" before I input the 1st number and "Enter weight in pounds:" before I input the 2nd number.  Please help me!

***I'm using Eclipse to write my programs and MinGW as the compiler if that's relevant.***

Comment: Your symptoms don't correspond to your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a [bug in eclipse](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732) and this has been reported by many people using eclipse and MinGW.

To fix this you could do one of the following:

- Add the following code at the start of the `main` function:

  ```
   setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
   setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  ```

  This will cause `stdout` and `stderr` to flush immediately whenever it is written to.
- Use `fflush(stdout)` after every call to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scanf_s` instead of scanf , i just ran it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest usying Putty if on Windows or command line on Mac OSX. Use "Wal Werror" compiler

Yes, you need to wait for it to display the output before enterning number.

E.g. you run the program
When this line appears

```
Enter height in inches:
```

then enter

```
 64
```

then when this appears

```
Enter weight in pounds:
```

Then enter

```
 120
```

then output should be as expected

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to user sscanf insted of scanf and add fgets to the top would be more logic.

It would be:

```
int height;
char buffer[32]; /*Add this to collect you data*/

printf("Enter height in inches:\n");
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin); /*Add this line to get value from keyboard*/
sscanf(buffer,"%d", &height); /*Change scanf to sscanf*/
```

and same of the other one