# Basic I/O in C — Program Chooses Random Int Rather Than Asking User

Tags: c, io

I am very new to C programming, trying to adjust going from Python to C where the I/O syntax is very different. I would like to ask the user to enter two integers, then return to the user the two integers they had entered followed by the two integers multiplied together. My code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a,b,c;
    printf("Enter a: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter b: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    c = a*b;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, a*b = %d", a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

The program does not allow the user to input a value, but rather chooses its own seemingly random integer, and the multiplication is also not correct. My output is as follows:

```
Enter a: 
Enter b: 
a = 2665720, b = -2147319336, a*b = -76879552
```

Comment: What's the output you get? I don't see issue with it?

Comment: What's the input you give, the program is Ok.

Comment: what values are you typing?

Comment: How are you running the program?  Are you using an IDE of some sort? If so, which one, and on which platform?  It's behaving a bit as if the `scanf()` operations both fail — as if there's nothing valid on standard input of the program.  Of course, you should be checking that they each return the value 1; if they don't, then the data in the variable is garbage.  Given the printed values for `a` and `b`, you have overflow when you calculate `c`, which is undefined behaviour, so any value in `c` is permissible.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, just tried my code with CodeBlocks and it worked fine so I suppose it's Eclipse's problem somehow.

Comment: There's a duplicate of this Eclipse problem somewhere around here. Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after each of your first two `printf()` calls. You shouldn't need to, but Eclipse seems to have this problem.

Comment: Always check return values of `scanf` functions, especially when reading integers. It's not even worth debugging before adding that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with input using scanf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029908/trouble-with-input-using-scanf)

Comment: Your program should work well provided you give it valid input, but eclipse's terminal emulator is very limited as far as I can remember, so I recommend you change the IDE, just that. You can try [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), it's great and it launches a custom terminal emulator for you so you can test your program correctly. Still, you can read my answer to see a different approach to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the problem is with your IDE not passing the input to your program, the observed behavior is because of `a` and `b` being uninitialized when you call `printf`, to avoid that you must verify that `scanf` succeeded reading the integer. Here I suggest a way of doing that, it might not be the best solution, but it takes care of inavlid input, looping until valid input is recieved.

You have to check for valid input since `scanf` wont initialize the passed parameters on invalid input, a better way to do that is with the `fgets` function in combination with `strtol` that way you can check the validity of the input data

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    int   a,b,c;
    char  string[32];
    char *endptr;
    int   valid;

    valid = 0;
    while (valid == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a: ");

        if (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin) == NULL)
            return -1;
        if (*string == '\n') /* invalid input */
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            continue;
        }

        a = strtol(string, &endptr, 10);
        if ((*endptr != '\0') && (*endptr != '\n')) /* invalid input */
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Enter b: ");
        if (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin) == NULL)
            return -1;
        if (*string == '\n') /* invalid input */
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            continue;
        }

        b = strtol(string, &endptr, 10);
        if ((*endptr != '\0') && (*endptr != '\n')) /* invalid input */
        {
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            continue;
        }
        valid = 1;
    }
    c = a * b;

    printf("a = %d, b = %d -> a * b = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

the uninitialized values will contain garbage, explaining the behavior you are observing.

With your program if you type any invalid string `scanf` will fail and you will try to print uninitialized values, you should at least check that it matched the correct number of arguments, like this

```
if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
```

something is wrong and you should either restart the program or, abort it.

Comment: @chux no, because I already take care of that here `if (*string == '\n')`.

Comment: Relatively minor to the point at hand, but: 1) You're missing `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Enter a: ");` and after `printf("Enter b: ");` 2) You don't check the return from `fgets()`, which will lead to trouble if the user does something like CTRL-D at the prompt. 3) `string` is a reserved identifier in C.

Comment: `string` is not a reserved identifier in c, it is a c++ class. And thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `string` certainly is a reserved identifier in C, along with every other identifier starting with `str` and another lowercase letter.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths can you post a link for an external resource to support that? I'm pretty sure `string` is not reserved in c, it is in c++ though.

Comment: @iharob: Read C11 Section 7.1.3.1, followed by C11 Section 7.31.13.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: 7.31.13 says "Function names that begin with `str`, `mem`, or `wcs` and a lowercase letter may be added
to the declarations in the `<string.h>` header."  A local variable or parameter called `string` is not a function and would shadow any function declaration of a hypothetical `string()` function added to the library.  You can't legitimately define a function called `string()` — you're treading on thin ice if you do.  And if you compile using GCC with `-Werror -Wshadow`, such a variable might land you in trouble.  But a type name is OK; a (non-global) variable name is mostly OK

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 7.31.1 limits these to "all external names described below are reserved" so agree a function scope variable name is technically OK, but it's a reserved identifier nevertheless, and presumably you wouldn't go around naming local variables `strcpy`, or `malloc`, for instance, even if it's not technically verboten.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: No (I wouldn't mess with variables called `strcpy` etc), and I often compile with `-Wshadow` too (and almost always with `-Werror`).  There's an element of risk assessment; I think you're being over-concerned — but your risk factors may be different from mine.  It is as well to be aware of the rules so that you break them consciously rather than accidentally.  You might or might not find it relevant that POSIX reserves all type names ending `_t`, amongst other things.

Comment: In this case, since it's almost a basic type, if you're in the habit of calling your strings `string`, you're probably in the habit of doing so a *lot*, so you'd potentially have an awful lot of variable names to change if we ever get a standard `string()` function that you wanted to drop into existing code. Admittedly, getting a standard `string()` function is probably on the more remote side of likely, compared to `strifptxycpy_s()` or such.